# Python: calculating log returns of a time series

Tags: python, pandas

I have such time series of data, where the 3rd row represents the close value of an index.

```
DAX 20150728 11173.910156
DAX 20150727 11056.400391
DAX 20150724 11347.450195
DAX 20150723 11512.110352
```

How can I calculate the log returns of the index using pandas python?

Thank you very much!

Regards

Comment: I don't know what log returns are but according to this http://www.vosesoftware.com/ModelRiskHelp/index.htm#Time_series/Log_return_of_a_Time_Series.htm isn't it log(close value) - log(first close value)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand log returns correctly then the following is what you want:

```
In [155]:

t="""DAX 20150728 11173.910156
DAX 20150727 11056.400391
DAX 20150724 11347.450195
DAX 20150723 11512.110352"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), header=None, sep='\s+',names=['exchange', 'date', 'close'], parse_dates=[1])
df
Out[155]:
  exchange       date         close
0      DAX 2015-07-28  11173.910156
1      DAX 2015-07-27  11056.400391
2      DAX 2015-07-24  11347.450195
3      DAX 2015-07-23  11512.110352
In [157]:

df['log return'] = np.log(df['close']) - np.log(df['close'].iloc[0])
df
Out[157]:
  exchange       date         close  log return
0      DAX 2015-07-28  11173.910156    0.000000
1      DAX 2015-07-27  11056.400391   -0.010572
2      DAX 2015-07-24  11347.450195    0.015411
3      DAX 2015-07-23  11512.110352    0.029818
```

**EDIT**

OK if it's intra log difference then you can do this succinctly using `diff`:

```
In [161]:
df['log return'] = np.log(df['close']).diff()
df

Out[161]:
  exchange       date         close  log return
0      DAX 2015-07-28  11173.910156         NaN
1      DAX 2015-07-27  11056.400391   -0.010572
2      DAX 2015-07-24  11347.450195    0.025984
3      DAX 2015-07-23  11512.110352    0.014406
```

Comment: log return is logarithm of values ratio. And I think it's more likely day-by-day than day-to-first.

Comment: EdChum thank you, this is exactly, what I need, actually I just want to keep the data format, and the name and only change the values of the 3rd column to the log returns.

Comment: so you want to overwrite that column? so something like `df['close'] = np.log(df['close']).diff()`?

Comment: Yes this is exactly, what I need: just to calculate the log returns in the 3rd column. All other columns should stay as they are.

Answer (score 10):

Be careful with

```
np.log(df['close']).diff()
```

as this will fail for indices which can become negative as well as risk factors e.g. negative interest rates. In these cases

```
np.log(df['close']/df['close'].shift(1)).dropna()
```

is preferred and based on my experience generally the safer approach. Whether you use +1 or -1 depends on the ordering of your time series. Use -1 for descending and +1 for ascending dates - in both cases the shift provides the preceding date's value.

In this specific example you need to set up the date column as index first, otherwise divide operation will fail:

```
df['close'].set_index("date",inplace=True)
```

Comment: Having thought about this, allow me to explain why the second way is better: consider the case where lots of consecutive prices are negative (e.g. `++----++`). The first way `np.log(df['close']).diff()` gives lots of `NaN`s, but the second way `np.log(df['close']/df['close'].shift(1))` gives non-`NaN` answers when there are consecutive negative prices (e.g. `--`), only giving `NaN`s at the boundaries (e.g. `+-` or `-+`).

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for the additional explanation!

Answer (score -2):

```
    import numpy as np
    df['log return'] = np.log(df[2]/df[2].shift(-1))
```

df is your dataframe which is descending sorted by date.

Comment: should be `np.log(df[2] / df[2].shift(1))`